# Flutter pub get failed (server unavailable) - Hanshake error in client

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Every time I run
`flutter pub get`
on my project, I get the floowing error.

```
Handshake error in client (OS Error: 

    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:359))

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
```

The issue came after I formatted my laptop and installed flutter all over again. My internet is fine and fast, I have been using it for a long time to develop apps.
`flutter doctor` runs well and doesn't return any issue.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48956085/1702602)?